# Why @Model haven't been passed to controller's action parameter by jquery script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I wanted to pass `Person` object which is `@Model` in `Details.cshtml`(.../Person/Details/id) view to the `Test` action in `PersonController` which returns partial view `Test.cshtml`.

The partial view is expandable/collapsable by the button so I use script. Everything works beside that `@Model` I try to pass to `Test` action is not passed-> it is null inside the `Test` action

Why it(model) hasn't been passed and how pass it?

Full code:

Script:

```
<script>
    function BtnOnclick() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Content("~/Person/Test")', 
            data: {
                person: '@Model' //HERE I TRY TO PASS PERSON
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#divpopup').css("display", "block");
                $('#btnExpand').css("display", "none");
                $('#divpopup')[0].innerHTML = data;
            }
        });
    }
    function CollapseDiv() {
        $('#divpopup').css("display", "none");
        $('#btnExpand').css("display", "block");
    }
</script>
```

Details View:

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.Person
[...]
<p>
    <input type="button" value="Expand" id="btnExpand"
           onclick="javascript:BtnOnclick();" />
</p>
<div id="divpopup" style="display:none">

</div>
```

Controller's action:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Test(Person person) {
           // ViewBag.Chk = parentEls;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("PASSED: ");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(person.FirstName); // IT IS NULL
            return PartialView(person);
        }
```

Partial view:

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.Person
<hr />
<h2>Survey 1</h2>

<input type="button" id="Coll" value="Collapse" onclick="javascript:CollapseDiv()" />
<dt>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Notes)
</dt>
<dd>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Notes)
</dd>
<hr />
```

COLLAPSED:

[image]

EXPANDED:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Is it bad if I just do:

in script:

```
 data: {
               id: '@Model.Id'
            },
```

in action:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Test(int id) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(id);
            Person person = db.Persons.Find(id);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("PASSED: ");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(person.FirstName);

            return PartialView(person);
        }
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with just passing the id if you don't need any other data. It all depends on your needs and requirements.

Comment: _"Is it bad passing just the id?"_. Arguably it better. Why degrade the performance of the site by posting back a whole lot of unnecessary data. But the question is why you need to do this. In your details view, you are rendering properties for `Person` which contains property `Notes`, so why not just render `Notes` in a hidden `<div>` and use the script to toggle the visibility?

Comment: @StephenMuecke It is the way showed me in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447575/how-to-create-collapsable-dropdown-expandable-partial-view-in-asp-net-mvc-web-a/25449214#25449214  I wanted a collapsable/dropdown partial view. Nobody said anything about hidden divs.

Comment: If the value of `Notes` is not dynamically changing while the user is viewing the page, there seems no point in making another call to the server. You could render a `button` followed by a `div` containing the `Notes` value, then on the button `click` event, toggle the visibility of the `div` and the `button`'s text

Comment: From the linked question, if `Notes` was say a large collection that you don't populate when getting `Person`, then the ajax call may be valid, in which case you might pass the `Id`, call a method such as `GetNotesForUser(int Id)` and pass back a partial view for `IEnumerable<Notes>`, but from the code you have posted, what you doing seems unnecessary.

Comment: @StephenMuecke This AJAX it already works but if it can be done simpler it should be. Could you show how to toggle visibility of div by button in the `Details.cshtml` view?

Comment: Sure, give me 15 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments, it seems unnecessary to make AJAX calls to get data that you already have access to when rendering the main view. An alternative could be to render the `Notes` value in a `<div>` and toggle the visibility using a `<button>`, so in the main view

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.Person

... // other display properties for Person

<button id="toggle"></button>
<span id="survey">Survey</span>
<div id="notes">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Notes)</div>
```

and the script

```
$('#toggle').click(function() {
  $('#notes').toggle();
  $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

Note the class name of the button is also toggled to change the appearance of the button from 'expanded' to 'collapsed' (similar to a treeview control)

[**Refer fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/py4baqy9/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
data: { person: '@Model' },
```

to

```
data: { person: @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)) },
```

[JsonConvert.SerializeObject](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm) is method from Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: I am new to jquery. Shouldn't it be:  `person: '@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))'`? If yes I get: http://s3.postimg.org/wte2svopf/expanded.png

Comment: it should be without quotes '' because you should pass JSON object instead of string. Also you should have dependency to Newtonsoft.Json(third party). Add this library to your project and "@using Newtonsoft.Json; " in the top of DetailsView

Comment: If you have not declared `@using Newtonsoft.Json` then you will need to specify the full namepsace.

Comment: I can mistake in some syntax points)) The main idea is to serialize model to json and then pass it to server

Comment: @ne4istb I corrected the syntax and posted the error in the link in the first comment to your post. Thank you for help.

Comment: @Yoda Does `Person` have a reference to itself? The serializer probably needs additional help from you to properly serialize the model. Try this with a much simpler model first to see the technique works.